# Slow response from Parse server

Tags: parse-server, back4app, mbaas

Just started to use parse server (back4app) with php api and I'm curious why it is so slow in several cases.

```
<?php

$query = new ParseQuery("Item");

$pagetitle = "List of tasks";    

if($_GET['category']!=''){
$category_like = "|".$_GET['category']."|";    
$query->fullText("itemCategory", $category_like);    
$pagetitle .= ' - Category: '.$_GET['categoryname'];     
} ?>
```

I've tried more service, but the others are even worse. A simple category list retrieval takes 1.5 - 3 even more sec. I assume it is not service related problem, just usage technical question.

What is the best solution in this case? REST API? Or Parse server should be handle my queries faster?

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can test the query via REST API on Dashboard > API Console. If you didn't face the same slow speed, I recommend you to check the PHP documentation: https://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#queries

Comment: It seems, query in query is the weak part. When I got rid of it, the queries was faster

Comment: full text querries in mongo are expensive.  You could look at how to index for them in mongo if that's possible, or better yet, use a specialized search for text.  we use algolia and love it.